# How to check which command is running by subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, bash, process, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run bash commands one by one using Python subprocess.
The first I tried is to call commands with Popen in loop but it runs all of the commands in one time. I can just wait for the command ending or return value but I don't want to. I have a main process and I would like to open ONLY one process next to it when the commands run one by one. I can't do it so I gave a list of commands to Popen. It works but I would like to know which command is running at a time.
For example there is 15 commands in a list and I run them with Popen and I would like to do something between the commands. (the commands take 2-4 mins to return with a value)
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: what about `subprocess.run()` ?

Comment: "This function is similar to the call() function. It runs the input commands and waits till all the commands are completed". My problem is that I want to do something while subprocess is running so I don't want to wait but I also don't want to start subprocesses in parallel. I just want to run ONLY ONE subprocess and when it finished run the next.
But in a loop I can't do it whitout wait and that blocks my main program too. If I don't use loop and give all the commands to one subprocess I don't know which command is running.